# Where is the Salt key in a Pylons/Pyramid app?

Tags: django, pyramid, pylons

I have a legacy 2010 Pylons app I want to replace with a newer Django one.

<s>In Django, it is my understanding that the Salt that is used in hashing passwords is the `SECRET_KEY` in the config file. Correct me if I am wrong. Pretty easy to find.</s> (I was wrong and corrected).

Anyway, the company isn't keen on resetting everyone's passwords due to the different hashing algorithm used in Django. So I was going to change Django's to match the Pylons one, or find a way to decrypt the Pylons hashed ones, and re-encrypt under Django's.

Problem is I don't know where the Salt is in the Pylons application after looking through documentation and Googling it. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: "It is my understanding that the Salt that is used in hashing passwords is the SECRET_KEY in the config file" - that's incorrect. There is a different salt for each password, and it is stored in the password field along with the algorithm, number of iterations and the hash. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/passwords/#how-django-stores-passwords) for more info.

Comment: Also, you can't decrypt hashes. The only way to get the original password would be to brute force it (which is hopefully infeasible if an appropriate hasher was used).

Comment: Ah ok, so basically, the only option is for everyone to reset their passwords under the new hashing algorithm?

Comment: No, it should be possible to write a custom hasher that works with your existing passwords. Django can [upgrade hashes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/passwords/#password-upgrading) when you log in, or you can use a [wrapped password hasher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/passwords/#password-upgrading-without-requiring-a-login) if your old hash is insecure.

Comment: The part I can't help you with is how to write that custom hasher, since I'm not familiar with Pylons.

Comment: I'll read those two links. Sounds promising!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single way of using a salt in Pyramid (or Pylons). The implementation of storing / retrieving a password hash to a data store is left for the application code.

That gives you much freedom.

One way of doing it could be to reproduce the code in Django and continue using this as your hashing algorithm since it's probably secure. A quick fix or proof of concept could be to install django and import code from it (though I would personally copy-paste small parts of the code if the license permits it, or just rewrite it). The hashing part you need is probably less than 15 lines once stripped to its minimum.

Also, I don't recommend doing as suggested in the comments on your question: migrating passwords as users log in. Because you'll be stuck with old passwords forever and you'll have to keep the code to handle them, plus the new code to handle new passwords, plus the migration code.

Comment: I just realized I gave an answer for the opposite problem: having a Django app that you want to migrate to Pylons or Pyramid. Sorry about that ;)